# Monotonicity of random variables

Tags: real-analysis, probability, measure-theory, inequality

Let $X\le Y$ be positive random variables. Now $E(f(X))\ge E(f(Y))$ for a strictly decreasing function $f$. But what can we say about the relation $f^{-1}(E(f(X))$ and $f^{-1}(E(f(Y))$? Suppose $f(x)=\frac1x$. Then clearly  $f^{-1}(E(f(X))\le f^{-1}(E(f(Y))$. I am interested in the general case, i.e. can we find a function $f$ such that the $\ge$ holds?

Comment: If $f$ is strictly decreasing, so is its inverse

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We always have $f^{-1}(E(f(X))) \leq f^{-1}(E(f(Y)))$. This s becasue $f^{-1}$ is decreasing too. Since $E(f(X)) \geq E(f(Y))$ we get $f^{-1}(E(f(X))) \leq f^{-1}(E(f(Y)))$